# JQuery animation not running in correct sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a game called 'Pointless'. Pointless here is a game show in the UK. Anyway, there is a countdown which counts down from 100 to whatever score the team got. I am trying to replicate this. For an example, please see this [video](https://youtu.be/zp05nfvbQq8?t=119).

Anyway, I am trying to replicate the countdown myself, however whenever I try the whole thing gets executed at once instead of one div at a time like it should. I need to hide those divs one by one.

Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fzf02cw/).

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    $('#' + i).toggle('slide');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `toggle` or any other animate functions in jQuery, it does not block the rest of the code. The animation continues on, while the rest of the code is running. You can add a delay for each of those blocks to start the animation.

You can try [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/xpmd3c1y/3/):

I also suggest you to use `.slideToggle('slow')` instead of `.toggle('slide')`.

```
$('#' + i).delay(i*100).slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes but thank you. I've learnt something and you've solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Downvote is probably because it would be better to post your code here as well instead of tricking and posting a dummy code. Maybe .. I don't know! Anyway, I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: @Amir Sorry, I just thought it would be easier to show a working example. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewKilburn It is, and thanks for posting a working example. but it would be nice to have that piece of code here as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `.toggle()` events (*along with other events*) are accually enqued and triggered after the execution of the entire for-loop. Or rather even if they where not, you are calling `toggle` on all of them nearly all at once, so they will all toggle at the same time. One way to get around it it to use a timer such as `setInterval` or `setTimeout`:

```
$('#Go').click(function(){
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
      i++;
      $('#' + i).toggle('slide');
      if(i > 10) clearInterval(timer);
    },100)
})
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3fzf02cw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Amir solution is greate. I want juste to add a small correction :

toggle method of jQuery doesn't have any arguments whose value could be `slide`.
Here is the correct syntaxe :

```
$(selector).toggle(speed,easing,callback)

speed  in [milliseconds, "slow", "fast"]
easing in ["swing", "linear"] (More easing functions are available in external plugins)
callback is a function
```